# Footer not fixed to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I tried having my footer stick to the bottom of the page, but the more content I add to my body, then it just goes out of bounds. I can't see a fault in my CSS, so hopefully one of you will be able to sort it.

```
.footer {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/367apj76/

Many Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute;` from `.footer`

**UPDATE:**

You should put everything but the footer in a div with the following CSS:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - *footer-height*px);
```

and the footer should go right after this div.

This will work because the new div cannot be smaller than the window size minus the footer, but grows with the window (that's what `vh` is for).

Comment: Still doesen't work, because if all text is removed, the footer will appear at the top of the page. :/
Unless, there is no way of doing it like I want it?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want the footer to be at the bottom of the window, but pushed down when the page is scrollable?

Comment: Notice my updated answer. Here is a working example: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/73Lzqzd9/1/). I had to subtract another 100px in the min-height because of the body's margin-top.

Comment: Hey there, I just implemented this, and it seems that anything that is added to the body has an effect on the footer. Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: Send a JSFiddle with the problem.